# Jquery returns [Object object] from POST function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to get a string from a php file, using a jquery post.

```
function getString(string) {
    return $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'scripts/getstring.php',
        data : { 'string': string }
    });
};
```

in the firebug console i can see that the desired string is found, but if i want to get it with

```
var blub = getString("test");
    alert(blub);
```

only "object Object" is shown.
just cant get where my mistake is..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Ajax request that is made to the server is performed asynchronously, so the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) method actually returns an object representing the request itself, rather than the actual response from the server.

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object.

You could use the `success` callback instead:

```
function getString(string) {
    return $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'scripts/getstring.php',
        data : { 'string': string }
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
    });
};
```

Or if you want to be a bit more flexible, you could take the callback function as a parameter:

```
function getString(string, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'scripts/getstring.php',
        data : { 'string': string }
        success: callback,
    });
};

getString('test', function(result) {
    alert(result);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an jQuery jqXHR object.

If you want to deal with the data from the HTTP response, then you need to add a `done` (or `success` handler.

```
blub.done(function (data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`object Object` is the expected response, because the data being returned *is* and object.

If you want to see the resultant object, try:

`console.log(blub)` instead and view it in the console.

This can then help you determine the correct path to the data you want to retrieve in the object.